# How to get total score specific to each row

Tags: elasticsearch

I need, Elasticsearch GET query to view the total score of each and every students by adding up the marks earned by them in all the subject rather I am getting total score of all the students in every subject.

```
GET /testindex/testindex/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : { 
          "match_all" : {}
        }
    }
 },
 "aggs": {
    "total": {
        "sum": {
           "script" : "doc['physics'].value + doc['maths'].value + doc['chemistry'].value"
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Output

```
  {
    ....
   "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "testindex",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "personalDetails": {
              "name": "viswa",
              "age": "33"
           },
           "marks": {
              "physics": 18,
              "maths": 5,
              "chemistry": 34
           },
           "remarks": [
              "hard working",
              "intelligent"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "testindex",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "personalDetails": {
              "name": "bob",
              "age": "13"
           },
           "marks": {
              "physics": 48,
              "maths": 45,
              "chemistry": 44
           },
           "remarks": [
              "hard working",
              "intelligent"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
     "total": {
        "value": 194
     }
  }
 }
```

Expected Output:

I would like to get total mark earned in subjects of each and every student rather than total of all the students.

What changes I need to do in the query to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like you want a script field rather than an aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "student": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "personalDetails.name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "doc['physics'].value + doc['maths'].value + doc['chemistry'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, be careful, for `student` `terms` aggregation you need a "unique" (something that makes that student unique - like a personal ID or something) field, maybe the `_id` itself, but you need to `store` it.

Comment: Thanks for giving solution; I forgot the bucket concept and may I know is there any tool are you using to form this query? I am using Marvel; If you have any such then please share it. Thanks

Comment: I'm using [Marvel's Sense dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/dashboards.html#sense) for all my tests.